# Rotating wheel of swipe-able 'cards'

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I would like to add a view to my app where I basically have a rotating circle of 'cards' (rectangles with rounded corners and information in them) that the user can swipe through. To get the illusion of the cards being laid out in a wheel, they would obviously need to disappear off the screen at a slight angle.

I was just looking for some guidance as to how I would go about this. I thought I would start with a UIScrollView with the cards sliding off horizontally and then work on the angle later? They would also probably need to have some sort of animation that centres them in the view when they decelerate to a stop.

Is there any tutorials online for this sort of thing? I did some searching and I couldn't find anything.

Here is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You could look at the iCarousel library https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel, It has a wheel layout which is very similar to your image

Comment: UIScrollView only supports vertical and horizontal dragging of subviews. Use UIGestureRecognizer to detect swipe and set transform property of UIView to rotated affine transform using CGAffineTransformMakeRotate.

Comment: @Satachito Ah, ok. That's disappointing. I have only two days to complete this app, so I don't want to start getting into new objects that I haven't tried yet right now. Thanks anyway!